# Compare NSManagedObject Array with an Array of Another "Object" Type Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift2

I am looking for an efficient way to compare an array of NSManagedObject and an array of essentially the same object/struct that I read from a file, i.e., the file "Item" has the same attributes as the CoreData "Item".  Here is the scenario.  I have a set of Items that I read from a tab delimited file.  In the first version of the game, I will store these items into a core data entity called "Item".

[CoreData entity relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzkdZ.png)

Then in version 2 of the game, I may add new items to the flat file or update existing items in the flat file.  The key I will use between the CoreData and file data is the itemId.  When I publish version 2 of the game, I fetch the version 1 NSManagedObject Item data into an array. I need to compare the NSManagedObject array with the version 2 file Item data.  I could loop through the file data and keep a counter for the location in each array, incrementing them as needed based on an itemId match or no match.  If there is a match, I want to use == to compare the data as all the attributes are the same, but the objects are different.  I don't want to store the file data object as a temp or dummy NSManagedObject.  If I do, I would then need to delete this temp object if the Item already exists or the item needs to be updates.

I am only dealing with 100s of items, so maybe it doesn't matter from a performance perspective.  Creating NSManagedObjects for comparison purposes and deleting them seems inefficient and conversely converting the NSManagedObject to a "file item" object or struct also seems inefficient.

So, the short version of the question is, how do I efficiently compare NSManagedObject array with an array of another "Object" type using Swift 2?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some additional research.  I found the following link:
[How to implement the new Core Data model builder 'unique' property in iOS 9.0 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894026/how-to-implement-the-new-core-data-model-builder-unique-property-in-ios-9-0-be)

1) I added a **mergePolicy** to my managedObjectContext definition, 4th line after the comment:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

2) as well as immediately save the managedObjectContext after inserting the objects, I can merge the datasets.

```
    if let contentLineArray = arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName("Item") {
        // Loop through each item in the item file.  Add each item and save.  
        // Using managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        for lineArray in contentLineArray {
            // skip the header line
            if lineArray == contentLineArray[0] {
                continue
            }

            // get the individual attributes from the line
            let lineAttributeArray = lineArray.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")

            let itemEntity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName(kItem as String, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext)
            let fileItem = NSManagedObject(entity: itemEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Item

            // set the properties of the managed object from the file object
            fileItem.itemId = Int(lineAttributeArray[0]) // unique key
            fileItem.slot = lineAttributeArray[1]
            fileItem.itemType = lineAttributeArray[2]
            fileItem.itemName = lineAttributeArray[3]
            fileItem.imageName = lineAttributeArray[4]
            fileItem.level = Int(lineAttributeArray[5])!
            fileItem.rarity = lineAttributeArray[6]
            fileItem.strength = Int(lineAttributeArray[7])!
        }

        // conflicts are managed at the time of save
        saveManagedContext()

        // used for unit testing and validating
//            let nameSpaceClassName = NSStringFromClass(Item)
//            let className = nameSpaceClassName.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last! as String
//            let sortItemId = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemId", ascending: true, selector: "localizedStandardCompare:")
//            let itemArray = CoreDataHelper.fetchEntities(className, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, predicate: nil, sortDescriptors: [sortItemId]) as! [Item]
//            print(itemArray)

    }

func saveManagedContext() {
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        #if DEBUG
            print("Managed context saved")
        #endif
    }
}
```

In essence, if I add "itemId" as a unique key or "Constraint" to my Item CoreData entity, CoreData allows for me execute an UPSERT.  **UP**date the record if the key exists or in**SERT** the record if the key doesn't exist.  This link also shows how to set the unique constraint for a CoreData entity.

[Core Data Framework Reference -> NSMergePolicy Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSMergePolicy_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Merge_Policies)